# Reactive search Datasearch Show suggestions with default Query and/or custom query, only getting results on the first character

Tags: reactjs, elasticsearch, reactivesearch

I have a reactive search Datasearch component that is running a default Query in order to exclude some results based on an Id. If I use the Datasearch **without** a default query, I am getting the suggestions just fine. But whenever I add the default query I can see the correct suggestions on the first character but after that it stops giving any suggestions.

I have been looking around in the render rawData and data variables. And I can see there are still rawData vars, but the Data input stops after the first hit. In addition, When I add a custom query, it seems that the suggestions do not really take this in account as it still shows suggestions outside of the subset created by the query.

My question is now, How to get the default query and custom query to work together with suggestions?
It seems that all the other components work correctly with my default query as in only showing results in the subset created by the custom query

Would be really helpful if someone could point me in the right direction on this one, Thanks in advance.

Update:
I want to add that when I look in the stateProvided object. Whenever I add the defaultQuery. The stateprovider stop showing the SearchState after one character in the searchbox. It seems like it's completely blocking the normal behaviour